# Bigger height in Firefox than in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, height

I have difference between Chrome and Firefox in the height of whole left column beginning on the navigation.
Here is comparative picture of the column in ff and chrome: 
http://tinypic.com/r/jhbynb/8

[Here][1] is the code:

```
<html>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

     <div class="space"></div>
     <div class="block">
         <h2>Some text</h2>
         <p>Number of visitors: 28</p>  
     </div>
</html>
```

CSS

```
nav
{
    width: 230px;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 8px
}

ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
} 

nav li a
{
    display: block;
}

nav a:link
{
    color: #718785;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    padding: 7px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}

nav a:hover
{
    font-weight: bolder;
}

nav a:visited
{
    color: #718785;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}

.space
{
    height: 34px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ZEqL/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is because different browsers have different default line-heights, so if you set your `nav li a` to a specific line-height, it will look the same on all browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/5ZEqL/4/

Comment: Thank you Chris, this was a problem.

Comment: I've fixed my problem, thx. I used `line-height:1.4` before. I replaced it with `line-height:20px`

Answer (score 0):

You can change css for a specific broswer

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
/** Your css here **/
}
```

Or you can use this: [Css browser selector](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/)